# DB2 - User Id disabled or restricted on Windows

Tags: windows, db2, db2-luw

I have DB2 11.1 installed on Windows 7. `'db2admin'` user account was created to access this. I was able to create, select and perform all necessary actions. Everything was working properly, until one fine morning it started giving me this error while connecting to database.

> SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or
>   RESTRICTED").  SQLSTATE=08001

I performed below things:

1. Reset the password
2. Verified if the user account is disabled on Windows.

[Account is not disbaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNW21.png)

3. Verified if the account is part of appropriate groups and ensured it has all necessary privileges on Windows

[User groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX21l.png)

4. Deleted the `'db2admin'` account and created a new one.

None of them worked and am still unable to figure out the reason for this error.

Is the error misleading? If so, any suggestions to verify logs or anything to figure out the root cause?

Any help in resolving this is highly appreciated

Comment: Did your machine join a Windows domain, by chance? What shows in db2diag.log when you try to connect?

Comment: Yes my machine is connected to my Organization's domain. However, as I have administrator privileges I am able to create and delete user accounts. I see these messages in the db2diag.log  :    _MESSAGE : Error Logon Type not granted for account_   and   _Password validation for user db2admin failed with rc = -2146500483_

Comment: In a domain DB2 will be authenticating the user against the domain, so changing local user's password is not going to help. Also make sure `DB2_GRP_LOOKUP` is set to `LOCAL`.

Comment: DB2_GRP_LOOKUP is set to local. I doubt DB2 here is authenticating against the domain. Because, this is a local DB2 setup with a local windows user account which are not connected to any domains or servers in the organization. Moreover, this was working in the past and have no idea what has changed now. I checked what does return code '2146500483' indicate in IBM website. It can be the user id was suspended or revoked. Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623221. But the user account is active and looks good when verified with windows command 'net user db2admin'

Comment: Additionally, when I try to connect with incorrect password it gives an INVALID PASSWORD error. But only when provided with right password it shows the "Userid disabled" error

Comment: Double check if there is both a local-account called db2admin *AND* a domain account called db2admin.  In an admin cmd.exe, use `net user db2admin`  and save the output, and then use `net user db2admin /domain` and save the output.  There needs to be only one such account.   Additionally check if there are any special characters in the password and eliminate them as a test.  Also verify that the db2admin account has the user rights assignment 'access this computer from a network' granted, and does not have the 'deny' equivalent set.

Comment: After verifying as you suggested, there is only one local user account. Also, password had no special characters. It is just alpha numeric. `db2admin` is added to local `Administrators` group which is already granted 'access this computer from a network'

Comment: Can you login locally via Windows-login to the Db2-server ? Can you use RUNAS to start a db2cmd.exe window running as db2admin?  Have you enabled Db2 extended security on windows?  If there have been domain policy changes recently (check with your Windows admin change control people). Do you get any additional details from DIAGLEVEL 4, or from Windows Event-Viewer?

Comment: I checked with my colleagues who had similar installations on their machines. They also faced same problem and they couldn't get past it. Looks like, windows updates or some policy changes as you suggested is preventing us to use local user accounts. Workaround we had for now is to use domain accounts to access database instances. Because we installed DB2 using domain account, this id was by default given DBADM rights. Using this id, so far, everything is working fine. Thank you all for your help!